# Занесение данных в sqlite с помощью функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, sqlite3

Пытался создать функцию с 3-мя аргументами, для занесения их в таблицу. Ошибку ловлю такую:

```
line 9, in add_user
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO users VALUES (date_time, username, user_id)''', (date_time, username, user_id))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: date_time
```

Что я сделал не так и  как это можно исправить?

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('name.db')
c = conn.cursor()


def add_user(date_time, username, user_id):
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO users VALUES (date_time, username, user_id)''')
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

date_time = '2006-01-05'
username = 'Admin'
user_id = 'oivb1381y319iu2bvi'
add_user(date_time, username, user_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помоему кавычка лишняя в запросе 
было:

```
c.execute('''INSERT INTO users VALUES (date_time,'username, user_id)''', (date_time, username, user_id))
```

поменять:

```
c.execute('''INSERT INTO users(date_time,username, user_id) VALUES (date_time,username, user_id)''', (date_time, username, user_id))
```

ps: добавил название колонок в запрос

Comment: изменил,ошибка не исчезла

Comment: @kriper5000 колонка date_time - существует в данной таблице ?

Comment: да, я создал таблицу этой строкой: ```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE users ('date_time', 'username', 'user_id')''')
```
потом её стёр

Comment: @kriper5000 
думаю это ваш случай :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142531/sqlite3-operationalerror-no-such-column